# Sort custom objects based on comparison between values of 2 different attributes

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have a custom object class as below which consists of 3 variables:

```
class DateObj {
  var startDate: Date?
  var endDate: Date?
  var updatedEndDate: Date?  
}
```

Below are the objects I created for it:

```
let obj1 = DateObj.init(startDate: 1/13/2022 7:00am, endDate: 1/13/2022 6:30pm, updatedEndDate: nil)
let obj2 = DateObj.init(startDate: 1/13/2022 10:30am, endDate: 1/14/2022 10:30am, updatedEndDate: 1/13/2022 10:30pm)
let obj3 = DateObj.init(startDate: 1/13/2022 11:30am, endDate: 1/14/2022 11:30am, updatedEndDate: 1/13/2022 7:30pm)
let obj4 = DateObj.init(startDate: 1/13/2022 1:30pm, endDate: 1/13/2022 5:30pm, updatedEndDate: nil)
```

Doesn't matter what the start date is, I want to compare values of endTime with updatedEndTime and want to sort such that the event that ends first (end time could be in endDate or updatedEndDate) should be first in the array and the event that ends last should be last in the array.

Note: updatedEndTime will always be less than endTime since the event could have ended earlier than expected time.

```
var inputDates = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]
var expectedOutputDates = [obj4, obj1, obj3, obj2] // Expected output after sort
```

***Code that I tried:***

```
inputDates.sorted { (lhs, rhs) in
    if let lhsUpdated = lhs.updatedEndDate, let rhsUpdated = rhs.updatedEndDate {
        return lhsUpdated < rhsUpdated
    } else if let lhsUpdated = lhs.updatedEndDate, let rhsEndTime = rhs.endDate {
        return lhsUpdated < rhsEndTime
    } else if let lhsEndTime = lhs.endDate, let rhsUpdated = rhs.updatedEndDate {
        return lhsEndTime < rhsUpdated
    } else if let lhsEndTime = lhs.endDate, let rhsEndTime = rhs.endDate {
        return lhsEndTime < rhsEndTime
    }
                    
    return false
}
```

My code is not giving me the expected output. Could someone help and let me know how to compare values from 2 different attributes for sorting an array?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want the elements to be sorted if the date is nil? Do you really need to declare your model properties as optional?

Comment: Yes the model properties are optional. I am using some library for it and don't have complete control over the model. I can set some date to endDate and startDate as default/limit, but updateEndDate could be nil. So assuming endDate will always be present, I would like to compare it with updateEndDate(if present) of other object or endDate of other object.

Comment: `13:30pm` ?????

Comment: Thanks for pointing! Updated to 1:30pm. Is a hardcoded data for example.

Comment: The sort works, but, `sorted` will not sort the original list, it will return a new list which is sorted.  Either assign the values back to a new variable or use `inputDates.sort` to sort the original list (assuming it's mutable)